# Why did my MPOW Bluetooth adapter stop working?

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth

Today, my MPOW wireless bluetooth dongle has stopped working.

I am using Ubuntu Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

This is the result of

```
$ dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
[    0.342413] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.354539] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-7f] only partially covers this bridge
[    1.905736] usb 1-4: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[   18.598464] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   18.598564] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[   18.598567] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   18.598573] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   18.598575] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   18.598580] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   18.620629] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0a hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0a lmp_subver=8761
[   18.623615] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[   18.623619] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin
[   18.624214] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin failed with error -2
[   18.624217] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: firmware file rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin not found
[   18.903187] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   18.903191] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   18.903194] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   81.482462] usb 1-3: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[   81.513386] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0a hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0a lmp_subver=8761
[   81.516378] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[   81.516383] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin
[   81.516406] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin failed with error -2
[   81.516410] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: firmware file rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin not found
[  368.433722] usb 1-3: Product: Bluetooth Radio
[  368.462755] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: examining hci_ver=0a hci_rev=000b lmp_ver=0a lmp_subver=8761
[  368.465747] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: rom_version status=0 version=1
[  368.465753] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: loading rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin
[  368.465776] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin failed with error -2
[  368.465780] Bluetooth: hci0: RTL: firmware file rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin not found
```

So it looks like `rtl_bt/rtl8761bu_fw.bin` has gone missing.

What could cause it to go missing, and how can I find it?

Answer (score 2):

I had to go to `/lib/firmware/rtl_bt`.

Then do `ls -alsth | grep 8761` to find a suitable file.

Then create a symlink:

`sudo ln -s rtl8761b_fw.bin rtl8761bu_fw.bin`

Then unplug and plug in the adapter.

Inspiration from:

https://fosspost.org/fix-bluetooth-rtl8761b-problem-on-linux-ubuntu-22-04/

Comment: I can confirm. This also works for Realtek devices.